# how to set focus to a textbox

Tags: wpf, focus

I have a windows with this controls.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    ///elemnts in row 0
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
        <ToolBar x:Name="Toolbar">
            <Label Content="TextPattern" />
            <ComboBox></ComboBox>
            <Button  Command="{Binding ScanCommand}">
                <Image Source="/Images/sacn.png"></Image>
            </Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding FaxCommand}" x:Name="FaxButton" PreviewKeyDown="FaxButton_PreviewKeyDown">
                <Image Source="/Images/fax.png"></Image>
            </Button>
        </ToolBar>
        <TextBox Width="{Binding ElementName=Toolbar,Path=ActualWidth}" x:Name="BodyTextBox" Focusable="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" Text="{Binding Body}"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2" >
        <Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"></Button>
        <Button Content="Cancel" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

When i use tab key for get focus, it go to savebutton after press tab of faxbutton. But i want to go to BodyTextbox.

I use `PreviewKeyDown` for set focus.

```
 private void FaxButton_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Key==Key.Tab)
        {
            BodyTextBox.Focus();
            BodyTextBox.SelectAll();
            FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, BodyTextBox);
        }
    }
```

But don't set Focus.

Answer (score 0):

When you load UserControl or Windowcontrol:
Please write this in the UserCOntrol_Load Event:

Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Input,

```
                      new Action(delegate ()

                      {
                          BodyTextBox.Focus();  // Set Logical Focus

                      Keyboard.Focus(BodyTextBox); // Set Keyboard Focus

                  }));
```

it will be automatically focus n also u can write content from keyboard without any tab pressing..

Hope this will work for U..

Thanks,
Praveen

Comment: Thanks, but i want to get focus when press key on Faxbutton.

Comment: KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="0"

Comment: Add this to your textbox control

Answer (score 0):

Remove the PreviewKeyDown event and Add KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue" in tool bar

```
 <ToolBar x:Name="Toolbar" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue">
```

Comment: Thanks, but when i use this code, it go to textbox, but don't go to element in toolbar.

Comment: yes,it's goes to the all element in tool bar. Please explain your question clearly.

Comment: I have multi control before Toolbar, move between controls with `Tab`. in last control of Toolbar, when press tab , go to save button instead of go to BodyTextBox.